# sample script to use sql commands in informatica cloud pre/post processing

Tags: informatica

Required sample script to run sql commands through pre/post processing commands. I tried by using sqlcmd but I'm getting this -

> I    CMN_1949 Error: [Pre/Post Session Command] Process id 5540. The
>   shell command failed with exit code 1.

Comment: What are those sql commands. Is it a select statements or any thing apart from that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Pre SQL` and `Post SQL` properties of your Target defined in the session's `Mapping` tab. There you can use pure SQL statements directly, there's no need for any shell scripting at all.

Comment: Informatica Cloud does not provide this functionality, it is very limited when compared to PowerCenter

Answer (score 0):

Trying running your script in bash to see what the real error is.